# Python not printing same as Arduino Serial Monitor

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to read some *float* values from the flash memory of an ESP32. They are stored one per line. I want to plot these values in Python, but the readings from its serial monitor vs Arduino's are all different.

Arduino sample code:

```
while(file.available()){

    num = file.parseFloat();
    str = String(num, 3);

    Serial.println(str);
    //Serial.println(num);
    
  }

  Serial.println("\nDone");
```

Python code:

```
while(1):
    line = ser.readline()   # read a byte string
    if line:
        string = line.decode()  # convert the byte string to a unicode string
        
        if ("Done" in string):
            break

        #num = float(string) # convert the unicode string to a float
        
        print(string)
        #print(num)
```

I tried both printing the float directly in Arduino as well as converting it to string, both work well in Arduino's Serial Monitor, neither works for the Python reading.

In the photo you can see some values are just thrash (ex -0.50.000). Any ideas for a fix? Thank you!
[image: Arduino vs Python]

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read something in python whether there is something to read or not, then checking if you have a value which will of course be true if you have any value in there, even if its trash. Try using `in_waiting` :https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by changing the baudrate down from 115200 to 9600.